# Grouping Specific Values together

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT Type, COUNT(Type) AS [Number of Applications]
FROM Applications
GROUP BY Type
```

So I have made a query that counts up the number of times a value occurs in a single column. Now I would like to group a number of them into a single result. I would like to take the results for China, Europe, Hong Kong, India, Japan, and Mexico and put them together into a category called "Foreign".

```
 Type      Number of Applications
 China             1
 Europe            1
 Hong Kong         1
 India             1
 Japan             1
 Mexico            2
 PCT               13
 Provisional       28
 U.S.              54
```

Any ideas on how I can group these together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good way is to have a look-up table, `Country` perhaps, and have a field for `IsItForeign` which will have one of two values, `Foreign` and `Domestic`.  Then you can join on `Country` (or `Type`, following what you have) and group by `IsItForeign`.  I have to guess you'll be needing this kind of slicing for more than today's report, so you may as well build it in.

The bad way is to "hard-code" it ...something like this:

```
SELECT 
Type, 
Iif(Type = "China" Or Type = "Europe" Or Type = "Hong Kong" Or Type = "India" Or Type = "Japan" Or Type = "Mexico", "Foreign", "Not Foreign") AS IsItForeign,
COUNT(Type) AS [Number of Applications]
FROM Applications
GROUP BY Type
```

The query above doesn't get you all the way to the summary you want, but I'm not quite sure what you want.  Maybe it's this, which keeps the non-foreign nations as distinct and lumps together the ones on your list:

```
SELECT 
Type, 
Iif( Type = "China" Or Type = "Europe" Or Type = "Hong Kong" Or Type = "India" Or Type = "Japan" Or Type = "Mexico", "Foreign", [Type]) AS IsItForeign,
COUNT(Type) AS [Number of Applications]
FROM Applications
GROUP BY Type
```

In any case, this gives you the basis.

There are many bad approaches besides this one.

As HansUp points out, using `IN()` is better:

```
IIf ( [Type] IN ('China', 'Europe', 'Hong Kong', 'India', 'Japan', 'Mexico'), 'Foreign', [Type])
```

You have to build this in SQL View, but of course you are comfortable with that.

I'm sure it's better to use a sub select query, as suggested by HansUp.  It's a step out of my comfort zone, but these days I'm in SQL Server and I'd better expand my zone!

Comment: In the `IIf` expression, use an `IN` list for the foreign countries: `SELECT sub.adjusted_type, Count(*) AS [Number of Applications] FROM ( SELECT IIf ( [Type] IN ('China', 'Europe', 'Hong Kong', 'India', 'Japan', 'Mexico'), 'Foreign', [Type]) AS adjusted_type FROM Applications) AS sub GROUP BY sub.adjusted_type;`